# how to retrieve text from website text boxes

Tags: delphi, browser

how can i retrieve text from a web sites text boxes in delphi for example suppose i type 
''tiger'' in google's search box how do i retrieve text from that search box would wm_gettext or getwindowtext work?
i am using delphi 7

Comment: Are you trying to get text from a running instance of internet explorer?  Or a tWebBrowser component?

Comment: i am trying to get text from a running instance of internet explorer/firefox/some other browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code.

**Only works  with internet explorer**. tested in Windows Vista,IE8 y Delphi 2007.

```
Uses
SHDocVw,
mshtml;

procedure GetTextFromEditIExplorer(ListStr: TStringList);
var
  ShellWindow            : IShellWindows;
  Web_Browser            : IWebbrowser2;
  reg_Shell_window       : IDispatch;
  Dummy                  : IHTMLDocument2;
  ovElements             : OleVariant;
  Document               : Variant;
  WindowsCount           : Integer;
  ElementsCount          : Integer;
  FormsCount             : Integer;
begin
  ShellWindow := CoShellWindows.Create;  //Provides access to the collection of open Shell windows
  for WindowsCount := 0 to ShellWindow.Count do     //iterate through number of windows in the Shell windows collection
  begin
    reg_Shell_window := ShellWindow.Item(WindowsCount);       //Returns the registered Shell window for a specified index.
    if reg_Shell_window = nil then Continue;    //go to next reg window
    reg_Shell_window.QueryInterface(iWebBrowser2, Web_Browser);   // determines if an interface can be used with an object
    if Web_Browser <> nil then
    begin
      Web_Browser.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument2, Dummy);
      if Dummy <> nil then
      begin
        Web_Browser     := ShellWindow.Item(WindowsCount) as IWebbrowser2;
        Document        := Web_Browser;
          for FormsCount := 0 to Document.forms.Length - 1 do
          begin
            ovElements := Document.forms.Item(FormsCount).elements;
            for ElementsCount := 0 to ovElements.Length - 1 do
            begin
              try
                if (CompareText(ovElements.item(ElementsCount).tagName, 'INPUT') = 0)  and  (CompareText(ovElements.item(ElementsCount).type, 'text') = 0) then
                ListStr.Add('Control Name ['+ovElements.item(ElementsCount).Name+']'+' Type  -> '+ovElements.item(ElementsCount).Type+'  ->  Value  ['+ovElements.item(ElementsCount).Value+']');
              except
                ListStr.Add('Error Reading element n° '+IntToStr(ElementsCount));
              end;
            end;
          end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
List : TStringList;
begin
   List:=TStringList.Create;
   GetTextFromEditIExplorer(List);
   ShowMessage(List.Text);
end;
```

**Edit :**

Omar unfortunately there is no simple solution to your problem. This is because each browser uses a different interface to interact with the information.

Here are a couple of suggestions

- Firefox uses [XPCOM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-xpcom.html), you can research about that.
- Try using [DDE](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=dde+delphi++iexplorer+firefox&aq=&aqi=&aq=&aqi=&aq=&aqi=&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=b70dc7eb892ba76c) (dynamic data exchange).
- You can use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), is a .net library wich work with firefox and iexplorer. you can see [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32754)  to learn how interact with a .net Assembly in delphi win32.

Bye.

Comment: thanks rruz :) this code seems hard! is their an easier way? i am not saying i wont be able to use this code but ill have to learn a couple of new things like ole and stuff and secondly i want to catch edit boxes from firefox as well.

Comment: +1 nice answer RRUZ.  I agree that there's no simple way to achieve this, particularly if multiple browsers are to be supported.  It's a shame there are no shared hooks for this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks,i have used dde to get url from browsers successfully but i coudnt find any help on how to use dde to retrieve text from webpage's text box. can you point to any example on using dde to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be by using a regular expression on the original HTML code from the page.

Comment: but can you do it on running instance of a public browser?please help!